# Orientation of QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

Is there is any way to design QWidget via Qt Designer for different orientations, like a landscape orientation or portrait orientation? Or only through the programatically rebuild of layout?

Comment: There's no support for that built-in (as widgets are designed for desktop, not mobile UI)

Comment: If you use the layout system, it adapts to the screen!